# How to run IO operation inside Observer.onNext that's called inside mainThread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I have a list of product that have an image as uri (field) that I need to save on the internal storage. The issue that I didn't find how to do it with the current code :

1. I got data from WS using retrofit
       `RestClient.getClient().getProducts()`
2. When I got data from WS I need to save them into Realm DB
3. After saving images on the Realm DB I try to save images on the internal storage but I can't because the `onNext` is called inside the `mainThread`.

   ```
   public void getProductsHandler(final Context context) {
   MyApplication application = MyApplication.get(context);

   rx.Observable<ProductResponse> faq = RestClient.getClient()
       .getProducts()
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler());

   faq.subscribe(new Observer<ProductResponse>() {
     @Override public void onCompleted() {
     }

     @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {

     }

     @Override public void onNext(ProductResponse response) {
       RealmService realmService = new RealmService(realm);
       realmService.setProducts(response.getResults());

       ((MainActivity) context).saveBannersIntoInternal(response.getResults());

     }
   });
   }
   ```

Any good solution ?

Comment: and if i may ask has something happend to creating `Thread`s and starting them?

Comment: @Super-califragilistic I thought on the same solution but wondered if possible to make it better

Comment: You shoud use rx operators for action chaining, in your case`flatMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to chain two operations, web service call and saving to DB, together.

```
RestClient.getClient().getProducts()
    .flatMap(response -> saveToDB())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

The last `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` call will let both Retrofit call and `flatMap` run on IO Scheduler.